# PHP: Getting last only element in associative array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a `for loop`.

```
$TOTAL_GOALS = 5;
for($i= 1; $i<=$TOTAL_GOALS; $i++) {
    $EACH_POST_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT item_id FROM likes WHERE item_id='$i'");
    $EACH_POST_TOTAL_LIKES = mysql_num_rows($EACH_POST_QUERY);
    $EACH_POST_RESULT = array();
    $EACH_POST_RESULT[$i] = $EACH_POST_TOTAL_LIKES;
}
```

In the loop, I'm dynamically firing queries and fetching result into a variable called `$EACH_POST_TOTAL_LIKES`.

I want to make an associative array based on this. So, I have created an array called `$EACH_POST_RESULT = array();`and pushing value into it.

The output I'm getting is the last element - example:

`3:16`

My expected output is -

`1:12
2:14
3:16`

I'm sending result to JS using this -

```
$SERVER_DATA = array("TG"=>$TOTAL_GOALS, "EACH_POST_LIKES"=> $EACH_POST_RESULT);
echo json_encode($SERVER_DATA);
```

Console is showing me only last entry. Why does array overwriting values and storing last one?

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line *before* the loop:

```
$EACH_POST_RESULT = array();
```

Otherwise it will be replaced with an empty array each time!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating `array` every time in the loop. I would suggest you to implement this in single query using `MySQL Between Clause` if you want to get count of all parameters once.

```
$TOTAL_GOALS = 5;
$EACH_POST_RESULT = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $TOTAL_GOALS; $i++) {
  $EACH_POST_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT item_id FROM likes WHERE item_id='$i'");
  $EACH_POST_TOTAL_LIKES = mysql_num_rows($EACH_POST_QUERY);
  array_push($EACH_POST_RESULT, $EACH_POST_TOTAL_LIKES);
}
```